# Regarding an identity involving $\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k\right]^{a/\lambda}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, gamma-function, poisson-process

Let $a, \lambda, \mu$ be real numbers with $a > 0$ and $\lambda > \mu$ (in attempt to make my life easier, I'm assuming that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive, as well).

I am trying to show that

$$\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k\right]^{a/\lambda} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k\frac{(a/\lambda)(1 + (a/\lambda))(2 + (a/\lambda)) \cdots ((k-1) + (a/\lambda))}{k!}. $$

(For those interested, this is from part of problem that deals with Poisson processes.)

Clearly, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k < 0$, since $\lambda < \mu$. Also, this equality clearly holds when $a = \lambda$. So, I've tried breaking it into the cases in which $a < \lambda$ and $a > \lambda$.

I've tried using falling/rising factorial representations of the sequence
$$\frac{(a/\lambda)(1 + (a/\lambda))(2 + (a/\lambda)) \cdots ((k-1) + (a/\lambda))}{k!},$$
and also (under the assumption that $\lambda > 0$) the fact that
$$\frac{(a/\lambda)(1 + (a/\lambda))(2 + (a/\lambda)) \cdots ((k-1) + (a/\lambda))}{k!} = \frac{\Gamma((a/\lambda) + k)}{\Gamma(a/\lambda)k!},$$
but nothing's popping out to me.

I assume there is some "obvious" "trick" here that I'm just not seeing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things simpler, let $\lambda/\mu = x$ and $a/\lambda = y$.  Left side is
$$ (1-x)^{-y}$$
Now look up the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).  See the first "special case".